# multistring in StringGrid via DrawCell.does not work as expected. Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

I use this code, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
procedure TTableForm.GamesGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Format: Word;
  C: array[0..255] of Char;
  A,B: Byte;
begin
 // Columns: Col_name,Col_rel,Col_desc are multistring ;
  if (ARow>0) and ((Acol = Col_name) or (Acol = Col_rel) or (Acol = Col_desc))  then begin

   Format:=DT_WORDBREAK;
   GamesGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
   StrPCopy(C,GamesGrid.Cells[ACol,ARow]);
   GamesGrid.Canvas.Font.Color:=clblue;

   DrawText((Sender as TStringGrid).Canvas.Handle,C,StrLen(C),Rect,Format);

  end;
```

[code working good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrTKX.png)

It worked ok, but if I select row it draws default and also draws over (using my code)

[draws default and also draws over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAkW0.png)

But I need always draw (always use DT_WORDBREAK) only with my code in both (selected or not)

Comment: Did you set the `TStringGrid.DefaultDrawing` property to False?

Comment: Yes, i tried to use it and then i need manually rewrite all draw methods(it is too hard) StringGrid. I just can't understand, why it is using default drawing. I tried use state (selected). I only need that it is use wordbreak in some columns in any state

Comment: When `DefaultDrawing` is True, the grid draws the cell its own way, even if you also draw on it, too. To avoid that, you have to set `DefaultDrawing` to False. But yes, that does mean you have to take full responsibility for drawing the entire cell. There is no getting around that. It is not THAT hard to do, it just takes a few more lines of code than what you already have. You just need to draw the cell's background before you draw the text. Set the `Canvas.Brush.Color` and then call `Canvas.FillRect()`

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try to do it.